# Two people play a strange game of darts

Tags: probability

Two people play a strange game of darts. At any throw there is a probability of: 2/5 that the
person throwing wins the game, which then ends; 8/15 that the person throwing gets another throw; 1/15 that the other player gets the next throw.

a) What is the probability that the first player wins on the fourth throw? (0.0635)

b) If the winner of the first game gets to start the second game, what is the probability
that the first player of the the first game gets to win the first two games? (0.7656)

I have calculated the probability for a). My working is: ((8/15)^3)(2/5) + 3((1/15)^2)(8/15)(2/5) = 0.0635. (Included for reference)

I am stuck on how to take on b) given the many ways that the person could win the game. To try and calculate P(Win|start 1st) I used my logic from part a to calculate the probabilities of the events of winning on the 1st game onward which I would then sum but I could not find a pattern that I can sum to infinity to get the required probability.

Comment: (1) Pl note that on this forum you need to first edit in your efforts, and where you are stuck. (2) Also does this "strange game" come from your imagination, some text book or from where ?

Comment: If you are sure on Part a, don’t ask about it. Then [edit] your question to tell us what your thoughts and ideas are.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for b)**

If $\ p_1\ $ is the probability that the first player wins the game, then the probability that the first player wins both games is just $\ p_1^2\ $, since he or she must start first in both games for this to occur.

You don't need to sum up the probabilities of all the possible ways the first player can win to work out the value of $\ p_1\ $.  After the first toss, the first player will either have won (with probability $\ \frac{2}{5}\ $), start again as the first player in a fresh game (with probability $\ \frac{8}{5}\ $), which he or she will then win with probability $\ p_1\ $, or become the second player in what is effectively a new game (with probability $\ \frac{1}{15}\ $), which he or she will then win with probability $\ 1-p_1\ $.  Do you see how this allows you to set up an easily solvable linear equation for $\ p_1 $?